# Unwanted Settings Directory

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a WPF application that targets .NET 4.0.  When the application starts the %ProgramData%\Company Name\Application\Version directory is created.  It is an empty directory.  I am not using My.Settings.  Why is this directory created and how can I prevent it from being created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the value of My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.AllUsersApplicationData creates the directory.

Using the Environment.GetFolderPath I can build the directory path without creating it.

IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData, Environment.SpecialFolderOption.None), String.Join("\", New String() {My.Application.Info.CompanyName, My.Application.Info.ProductName, My.Application.Info.Version.ToString()}))

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that this doesn't happen by itself, and trying it out by creating an empty WPF VB.Net project, just changing the company name and the running it, I can't find that any directory like that has been created.

So since I think it is somewhere in your code that you're doing this, the suggestions I can come up with would be:

1. Search for the word `ProgramData` in your code just in case.
2. Create a new VB.Net WPF project and compare it with your current project using some good diff tool (if you don't already have any, I use WinMerge which seems ok, but there are lots of other free ones).
3. Try to step through your code and check after each possible line if the directory has been created. It would seem likely that it would be created in the beginning of your app since it happens every time you start it, so you might be able to track it down fairly quickly in this way.

Comment: A couple of well placed breakpoints did help me narrow it down.